# SQL Procedure call from mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, mybatis, ibatis

All, I am trying to call a SQL procedure from Java user Mybatis, But i am getting 
"java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1". Googling this doesnt give me the right answers.
Below is my code what i wrote. I am using mybatis first time, Can anyone please guide me.

Mepper.xml :---

```
<select id="addHardwareList" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
          {
                 call P_HW_SW_CRUD.SAVE_HARDWARE_INVENTORY(
                 #{pDataIn,javaType=Object,jdbcType=ARRAY,jdbcTypeName=TAB_IDESK_HW_INFO,mode=IN,typeHandler=com.tristar.idesk.mybatis.mapper.HardwareInventoryHandler}
                 #{pMsgCodeOut,javaType=Long,jdbcType=DECIMAL,mode=OUT}
             )
         }  
  </select>
```

Here is where i setup my MAP --

```
public void addUpdateInventory(JsonNode jsonNode) {

        Map<String, ?> inventoryMap = getMapFromJSONAddUpdate(jsonNode);
        HashMap<String,Object> returnMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        Long pErrodCodeOut = null;
        String pErrorMsg = null;

        returnMap.put("pDataIn", (List<HardwareInventoryBean>) inventoryMap.get("beanHardwareList"));
        returnMap.put("pErrorCodeOut", pErrodCodeOut);
        //returnMap.put("pErrodMsgOut", pErrorMsg);
        hardwareInventoryMapper.addHardwareList(returnMap);
    }
```

I also implemented a custom type handler to map my java bean attributes to oracleType Object.

```
public class HardwareInventoryHandler implements TypeHandler{

    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        try{
            //new RecLoaderService().getJSONObj("REC_ICAST_CLAIMANT_INFO", "TAB_ICAST_CLAIMANT_INFO", jsonObject, i, ps);
            System.out.println(parameter);
            List<HardwareInventoryBean> hwInventoryList = (List<HardwareInventoryBean>) parameter;
            System.out.println("Parameter Here --"+parameter);
            StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(InventoryConstants.HW_DB_REC_TYPE_NAME, ps.getConnection());
            STRUCT[] structs = null;
            structs = new STRUCT[hwInventoryList.size()];
            for (int index = 0; index < hwInventoryList.size(); index++) {
                HardwareInventoryBean hwInventoryBean = hwInventoryList.get(index);
                Object[] params = new Object[12];
                params[0] = hwInventoryBean.getHwId();
                params[1] = hwInventoryBean.getHwTypeId();
                params[2] = hwInventoryBean.getHwModelId();
                params[3] = hwInventoryBean.getAssetId();
                params[4] = hwInventoryBean.getDateReceived();
                params[5] = hwInventoryBean.getHwPrice();
                params[6] = hwInventoryBean.getHwStatus();
                params[7] = hwInventoryBean.getHwWarranty();
                params[8] = hwInventoryBean.getCreatedBy();
                params[9] = hwInventoryBean.getCreatedDate();
                params[10] = hwInventoryBean.getModifiedBy();
                params[11] = hwInventoryBean.getModifiedDate();

                System.out.println("---------> " +hwInventoryBean.getHwId());

                STRUCT struct = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), params);
                structs[index] = struct;

            }

            ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(InventoryConstants.HW_DB_TEB_TYPE_NAME, ps.getConnection());
            ARRAY oracleArray = new ARRAY(desc, ps.getConnection(), structs);
            ps.setArray(i, oracleArray);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JSONObject getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName)
            throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public JSONObject getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex)
            throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public JSONObject getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex)
            throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Mapper Interface ----

```
public void addHardwareList(HashMap<String, Object> returnMap);
```

My SQL Procedure code is :-

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY P_HW_SW_CRUD AS  -- body
PROCEDURE save_hardware_inventory (hw IN TAB_IDESK_HW_INFO, nu OUT NUMBER) IS
ERROR_CODE NUMBER(10);
ERROR_DESC VARCHAR2(200);
   BEGIN 
   nu := 10;
   FOR i IN 1 .. hw.COUNT
   loop
   if(hw(i).HW_ID <> 0) then
   INSERT INTO IDESK_HW_INVENTORY VALUES (IDESK_HW_INVENTORY_seq.nextval, hw(i).hwTypeId , hw(i).hwModelId,hw(i).assetId    
        , hw(i).dateReceived    , hw(i).hwPrice ,hw(i).hwStatus , hw(i).hwWarrenty  , hw(i).createdBy , sysdate,hw(i).modifiedBy, sysdate); 
 else 
 update IDESK_HW_INVENTORY set HW_TYPE_ID=hw(i).hwTypeId,HW_MODEL_ID=hw(i).hwModelId,ASSET_ID=hw(i).assetId,DATE_RECEIVED=hw(i).dateReceived,HW_PRICE=hw(i).hwPrice,HW_STATUS=hw(i).hwStatus,HW_WARRENTY=hw(i).hwWarrenty,MODIFIED_BY=hw(i).modifiedBy,MODIFIED_DATE=sysdate where HW_ID=hw(i).HW_ID;
 end If;
        end loop;
         Exception
   when others then
   ROLLBACK;
   ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
   ERROR_DESC := SQLERRM;

   END save_hardware_inventory ;
PROCEDURE save_software_inventory (sw IN TAB_IDESK_SW_INFO ) IS
ERROR_CODE NUMBER(10);
ERROR_DESC VARCHAR2(200);
   BEGIN   
   FOR i IN 1 .. sw.COUNT
   loop
   if(sw(i).SW_ID <> 0) then
   INSERT INTO IDESK_SW_INVENTORY VALUES (IDESK_SW_INVENTORY_seq.nextval, sw(i).SW_VENDOR_ID , sw(i).SW_VERSION_TITLE,sw(i).QUANTITY    
         , sw(i).PRICE  , sw(i).CONTRACT_ACOUNT_NUM ,sw(i).SW_STATUS    , sw(i).CREATED_BY  ,sysdate, sw(i).MODIFIED_BY , sysdate); 
  else 
 update IDESK_SW_INVENTORY set SW_VENDOR_ID=sw(i).SW_VENDOR_ID,SW_VERSION_TITLE=sw(i).SW_VERSION_TITLE,QUANTITY=sw(i).QUANTITY,PRICE=sw(i).PRICE,CONTRACT_ACOUNT_NUM=sw(i).CONTRACT_ACOUNT_NUM,SW_STATUS=sw(i).SW_STATUS,MODIFIED_BY=sw(i).MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE=sysdate where SW_ID=sw(i).SW_ID;
 end If;
         end loop;
  Exception
   when others then
   ROLLBACK;
   ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
   ERROR_DESC := SQLERRM;

   END save_software_inventory ;
END P_HW_SW_CRUD ;
```

Comment: There was a typo in the code , i updated the code above and now i am getting a type cast exception ..  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this issue by using the innermost delegate connection

```
 ((DelegatingConnection)ps.getConnection()).getInnermostDelegate().
```

Next error was because of typo error in mapper.xml("," missing in the select id in mapper.xml). See below for the correct syntax.

```
select id="addHardwareList" 
statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
      {
             call P_HW_SW_CRUD.SAVE_HARDWARE_INVENTORY(
             #{pDataIn,javaType=Object,
jdbcType=ARRAY,jdbcTypeName=TAB_IDESK_HW_INFO,
 mode=IN,typeHandler=com.tristar.idesk.mybatis.mapper.HardwareInventoryHandler}
             #{pMsgCodeOut,javaType=Long,jdbcType=DECIMAL,mode=OUT}
         )
     }
```

Comment: It seems that it's still out of syntax

Answer (score 3):

Believe you need a [CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) (which by the way is a subclass of [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)) and that you need to use 'registerOutParameter'.

See if [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/) helps.

Comment: :- CallableStatement will be created by mybatis itself cause i defined the statementType="CALLABLE" in my select ID.

Comment: But @VaibhavDixit you set Parameter using PreparedStatement?

Comment: Yes, Thats why mybatis documentation says... I saw several example, They are are doing the same way.

Comment: This error is solved , It was cause of a type cast issue. I need to get the Innermost connection.. ((DelegatingConnection)ps.getConnection()).getInnermostDelegate().

Comment: Now i am getting a new exception - Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 3, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol &quot;&quot; when expecting one of the following:
   . ( ) , * @ % &amp; | = - + &lt; / &gt; at in is mod remainder not
   range rem =&gt; .. &lt;an exponent (**)&gt; &lt;&gt; or != or ~= &gt;= &lt;= &lt;&gt;
   and or like LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ as between from using ||
   indicator multiset member SUBMULTISET_